# Launch Waveform for Distributed Systems targeting arm and x86

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a simple waveform that encodes and decodes an audio stream (a loopback for testing). The encoder and decoder components have a softpkg dependency. I am able to launch this waveform using only GPP Device of a x86 machine. I have all the deps and components cross compiled with the spd.xml properly configured for another implemetation (cpp_arm using an armv7l processor).
When I try to launch this waveform using an Arm GPP device registered in the Domain to run The Encoder and Decoder components.. I got the following:

```
Failed to create application: codec_loopback_234_112125459 Failed to satisfy device dependencies for component: 'Decoder' with component id: 'Decoder_1:codec_loopback_234_112125459_1'
IDL:CF/ApplicationFactory/CreateApplicationError:1.0
```

-----------EDIT--------------

GPP processor_name does not match:

```
2017-08-24 09:23:35 DEBUG ApplicationFactory_impl:1764 - Trying to find the device
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE ApplicationFactory_impl:2030 - User-provided DAS: Component: 'Decoder'  Assigned device: 'DevMgr-GPP:GPP-cortexa9hf-neon'
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE ApplicationFactory_impl:2067 - alloc prop size 0
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:296 - Allocating against device DevMgr-GPP:GPP-cortexa9hf-neon
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:403 - Attempting to match processor armv7l against 12 properties
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:cdc5ee18-7ceb-4ae6-bf4c-31f983179b4d device_kind
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:0f99b2e4-9903-4631-9846-ff349d18ecfb device_model
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:fefb9c66-d14a-438d-ad59-2cfd1adb272b processor_name
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:415 - Performing comparison operation '' eq 'armv7l'
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:4a23ad60-0b25-4121-a630-68803a498f75 os_name
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:0f3a9a37-a342-43d8-9b7f-78dc6da74192 os_version
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:506102d6-04a9-4532-9420-a323d818ddec mcastnicIngressCapacity
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:eb08e43f-11c7-45a0-8750-edff439c8b24 mcastnicEgressCapacity
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:8dcef419-b440-4bcf-b893-cab79b6024fb memCapacity
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:3bf07b37-0c00-4e2a-8275-52bd4e391f07 loadCapacityPerCore
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE prop_utils:408 - Checking property DCE:72c1c4a9-2bcf-49c5-bafd-ae2c1d567056 loadCapacity
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:419 - Device did not match requested processor
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE AllocationManager_impl:301 - Matching failed
2017-08-24 09:23:35 DEBUG ApplicationFactory_impl:1769 - Unable to allocate device for component Decoder_1:codec_loopback_236_092321548_1 implementation cpp_arm
2017-08-24 09:23:35 DEBUG ApplicationFactory_impl:1852 - Failed to satisfy device dependencies for component: 'Decoder' with component id: 'Decoder_1:codec_loopback_236_092321548_1'
2017-08-24 09:23:35 ERROR ApplicationFactory_impl:1577 - Error in application creation; Failed to satisfy device dependencies for component: 'Decoder' with component id: 'Decoder_1:codec_loopback_236_092321548_1'
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE ApplicationFactory_impl:3497 - Removing all bindings from naming context
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE ApplicationFactory_impl:3507 - Unbinding the naming context
2017-08-24 09:23:35 TRACE ApplicationFactory_impl:3513 - Destroying naming context
```

GPP processor_name value is not set in prf.xml, but here's what the property tab shows me: [GPP processor_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiHdX.png)

```
<simple id="DCE:fefb9c66-d14a-438d-ad59-2cfd1adb272b" mode="readonly" name="processor_name" type="string">
    <description>SCA required property describing the CPU type</description>
    <kind kindtype="property"/>
    <kind kindtype="configure"/>
    <kind kindtype="allocation"/>
    <action type="eq"/>
  </simple>
```

Comment: Turn the domain and the device manager that is running the GPP's log level up to at least the debug level and rerun. It will then display what dependency was checked and failed.

Comment: thanks Youssef, I think this issue is solved